# classes of same module not available after using import

Tags: angularjs, typescript, service, typescript-typings

Below are my code in `typescript`

I have the below module which imports `ts-events`

```
import {SyncEvent} from 'ts-events'

module MyModule{
export class MyService{
    }
}
```

I am trying to extend this `MyService` class in same module but in different file

```
module MyModule {

export class MyExtendedService extends MyService{ //this line throws compilation error
    }
}
```

If I remove importing `ts-events`, its not throwing exception and working fine.
I tried the solution as in [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2135), but not working. How can I overcome this

Comment: Don't mix namespace (you are using the keyword `module` as namespace here) with import/export.
Clean up your code as a module first. And also please how what is the compile error.

Comment: the code is already as module only.

Comment: The error is cannot find name 'MyService'

Answer (score 0):

`module MyModule { ... }` is the deprecated form of `namespace MyModule { ... }`

When you are writing module (ES2015/ES6/ESM or CommonJS), you typically do not need `namespace`.

The problem you have is that the `namespace Mymodule` in these two files are not shared. They don't mix together.

That's why you get the error of cannot find name `MyService`.

What you need to do is to get rid of the `module MyModule {...}`

```
// a.ts
export class MyService { ... }

// b.ts
import { MyService } form './a'
export class MyExtendedService extends MyService { ... }
```